# Azure AD and ASP.NET Identity + OWIN, which approach to use?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, owin, azure-active-directory

We have ASP.NET application which has been in production for last 4-5 years. Now im trying to implement new authentication using Azure AD, ASP.NET Identity & OWIN framework.  Our application users also need to have access to cloud app “BOX” which already supports SSO using Azure. So idea is to add our application into Azure AD and configure SSO.

**NOTE: We DO NOT have Active Directory on premises, i just want to use Azure AD for web app authentication.**

And as usual after going through lot of documentation on MSDN I am confused which authentication mechanism I should be using.

**1st Approach - Based on Microsoft article** [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/)
I have configured the following packages using Nuget

```
    PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect  
    PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies  
    PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Then I have configured app in Azure AD, and then in ASP.Net application configure **'ida:ClientId'**, **'ida:Tenant'** and **'ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri'** in app settings. And then you call the following code at startup  *(and also do some extra step as per the article)*

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        });
}
```

**2nd Approach – Based on Template provided by VS 2013 Ultimate**
Here when you create new application using VS 2013 and configure the authentication using Organizational Account option, it adds the following appsettings
'**ida:FederationMetadataLocation**', '**ida:Realm**' and '**ida:AudienceUri**' and then adds the code to authenticate user

Questions
1> I am not sure which approach I should be using, and what’s the difference.
2> As per Microsoft video [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Identity-103-Vittorio-creates-an-application-that-will-authenticate-against-Active-Directory?ocid=EntriesInArea) if you create application using 2nd approach, Visual Studio will create application in Azure AD for that tenant. But its does not create anymore, has this changed recently? Do we always have to manually create application in Azure AD?

**EDIT1**
When i create new MVC or Web Form app in VS 2013 and configure authentication, there are 4 options. 2 of them are 'Individual Accounts' and 'Organizational Accounts'. The approach 1 mentioned above is for "Individual Accounts" and Approach 2 is for Organizational Accounts. However i still dont know when should i use one over other? Why one use client id vs another use restful API (federation metadata)? If i want same user to have access to multiple cloud applications which approach should i use?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want, but this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782804/supporting-individual-user-accounts-and-organizational-accounts-in-mvc5-asp-ne) and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006822/is-it-possible-to-have-both-azure-ad-and-individual-account-authentication-in-on) might help get you in the right direction.  In the first case, I am enabling local ASP.NET Identity login, ASP.NET Identity external identity provider login AND Organizational Login (via Azure AD)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry for the confusion. What you are experiencing is the stratification of multiple versions as the technology evolves. Let me clarify a couple of points.

1. Visual Studio 2013 shipped before the OWIN middleware for web sign
   on was available. Because of that, the ASP.NET project templates
   were still based on old technology (Windows Identity Foundation) and
   old protocols (ws-federation).
2. After VS2013 shipped, we developed new classes (which you encountered in the quickstart article) which support web sign on through a more nimble object model (OWIN middleware) and via more modern protocols (openid connect). You have the choice of using such classes "manually", as described in the quickstart, or to use the NEW templates in Visual Studio 2015 - which abandon the old tech (WIF) and automate a) the generation of projects using OWIN middleware b) the provisioning of one entry for the app in an Azure AD tenant of your choice.
3. The choice of Individual accounts vs "work & school" accounts allows you to select whether your application authenticates users one by one (for the former) and owns all user's details, or if you want your app to outsource authentication to the organization from which your users are coming from. If you want to use Azure AD, you want to do the latter: authentication is done by Azure AD, you just want your app to be configured to redirect to Azure AD when it's time to authenticate a user.

Comment: @vironet thanks for clarification. But we have a situation where we need to use 'individual user authentication and facebook/google' and also we need to include Azure AD authentication. Can you point me in the right direction. So, far i have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660780/asp-net-identity-using-password-and-azure-active-directory-authentication question and it has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all AzureAD samples.
https://github.com/azure-samples?query=active-directory

In particular these OIDC samples should get you going. Let me know if you get stuck.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnet5

Comment: both the articles use the same steps as I mentioned above in approach 1. What I wanted to know what's the difference between these 2 approaches Why they have different app settings? Why one apprach use clientid  vs another use restful API..like federation metadata

Comment: One is using WsFederation which uses terms related to WSFed: FederationMetadataLocation, Realm, AudienceUri. One is using OpenIdConnect, which users terms: Authority, ClientId, Audience. WsFed and OIDC are two protocols for obtaining an identity from an Identity Provider (IDP). I would recommend OIDC and the industry as a whole is moving that way.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i was looking for. However if i create a new application using VS 2013 Ultimate Update 5. and configure it to use Work and School accounts, it still uses WSFedderation approach. Not sure why its not using the new approach OpenIDConnect

Comment: The easiest way is to use OWIN. Katana was the model that has been expanded and made first class in the new ASP.CORE being release this year. For OWIN see: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katan . For ASP.CORE see: https://github.com/aspnet/Home

Comment: im using .NET 4.5.1 with MVC 5.

Comment: Then you can use Katana. ASP.CORE will support 4.5.1, but it hasn't shopped yet.